# How to use DZ.player.playExternalTracks

Tags: javascript, deezer

I am trying to use Deezer Javascript SDK to play external music but I only managed to get error "**SECURITY EXCEPTION, you are not supposed to use this function !**" in the JS console.

An extract of the code I use (based on http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/loadtracks and http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/example-basic ):

```html
<input type="button" onclick="DZ.player.playExternalTracks([{                                                                                                                         
url: 'http://cdn-preview-a.deezer.com/stream/a4e149e52e2ffdc4f057661b40ba7ee3-1.mp3',                                                                                                         
title: 'Title',                                                                                                                                                                               
artist: 'Artist name'                                                                                                                                                                         
}]); return false;" value="External"/>
```

How to make it work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DZ.player.playExternalTracks function is only available for Deezer apps for now (e.g. running inside Deezer website or mobile apps).

Comment: OK, do you know if it is planed to be allowed from everywhere ?

Comment: It's in the plans but no deadline to announce.